# Laravel: I can not visualize images when uploading the web to my Hosting

Tags: linux, laravel, hosting

I have a web developed in Laravel, in local I can visualize all the content of the web without problems, I have uploaded the web to my hosting in the domain folder where I want to have the web (it is a shared hosting with several domains), I configured the base of data and modified the .htaccess file. The web loads, however it does not display the logo or the images stored in public / images.

Any idea what this is? I appreciate any guidance

I advance that my web is not in the public_html folder, because that folder is occupied by another web. All the files are in a domain.com folder

This is the method I'm using to call the images `src="{{asset('images/test/home/banner-home.jpg')}}"`

I have already checked and there are no syntax errors between uppercase and lowercase.

this is the error that I receive in each image:

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Is your website hosted on a subfolder?

Comment: You probably typed something like `<img src="/images/image.jpg">` with the `/` in front. Now it searches for the root folder instead of the current folder.

Comment: try `{{asset('folder/image-name.png')}}` to access the images in the public folder or bad way but works `{{url('/'.'/folder/'.$path-name)}}`

Comment: Hi again, as extra information, this is the method I'm using to call the images src="{{asset('images/test/home/banner-home.jpg')}}"

I have already checked and there are no syntax errors between uppercase and lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it this way:

1. in  your domain.com, create another folder and move all the files and folders to the newly created folder.
2. from the newly created folder, copy all the files and folders in public back to domain.com
3. open your index.php in domain.com and configure this:

   i. require **DIR**.'/newlycreatedfolder/vendor/autoload.php';

   ii. $app = require_once **DIR**.'/newlycreatedfolder/bootstrap/app.php';
4. i hope all your header files are called using: `{{ asset() }}` and your logo using `{{ url() }}`

Comment: Hi samju, I have not tried your suggestion yet, when I try I'll let you know